# calculate time complexity for this solution

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, pseudocode

I have the following code. I think the solution has O(n^2) because it is a nested loop according to the attached image. can anyone confirm?

```
function sortSmallestToLargest(data):
      sorted_data={}

      while data is not empty:
         smallest_data=data[0]

         foreach i in data:
            if (i < smallest_data):
               smallest_data= i

         sorted_data.add(smallest_data)
         data.remove(smallest_data)

      return sorted_data
```

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob2bn.png)

Comment: does your program run endlessly?

Comment: Minor optimization: don't remove the first element, that takes a lot of time because you have to shuffle every other element after it back into its original position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I see what you are doing! Yes, you are right, it's `O(n²)`, because you're always looping through every element of data. Your data will decrease by one every loop, but because with O complexity we don't care about constants, we can say it's `O(n) for each loop`. Multiplying (because one is inside the other) we have `O(n²)`.

Comment: Just a tip:  `sorted_data` could be a list, instead of a set (aka object or map)

Comment: ok, thank you very much for you time and effort